# How to highlight selected row in a listbox for windows phone

Tags: listbox

I am trying to highlight the selected row in a list box and I am having difficulty getting it to work.  I have looked online and the solutions that I found either involve using style.resources or style.trigger, both of which my program is saying aren't recognized.

The xaml code for my listbox is as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="selectClassCanvas_ListBox" Width="448" Height="488" 
         SelectionChanged="selectListSelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
         Canvas.Left="4" Canvas.Top="54" Background="White">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ListBoxItem Width="450" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                   Foreground="Black" Height="50" 
                   FontSize="17"/>
      </ListBoxItem>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Can someone please give me some instruction on how to get the selected row of a listbox to highlight?

Comment: Why do you say style.resources and style.trigger aren't recognized ? Did you think to add `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HighlightItemStyle}"` in ListBox ?